# How do I retrieve media from a reference field?

Tags: entities, database

Inside a node type, I have a reference field to target a media.
With a db select, I need to load all related medias of the nodes.
For this I use this code:

```
$database = \Drupal::database();
$result = $database->select('media_field_data', 'm')
->fields('m', ['mid'])
->condition('m.bundle', 'gallery')
->leftjoin('node__field_related_gallery', 'n', 'media_field_data.mid = node__field_related_gallery.field_related_gallery_target_id')
->leftjoin('field_related_gallery_media_field_data', 'd', 'node__field_related_gallery.entity_id = field_related_gallery_media_field_data.nid')
->range(0, 5)
->execute()
->fetchAllKeyed(0, 0);
dpm($result);
```

But with this code I get an error and don't get the related mids. If I remove the line with the leftjoin I get the mids.

How can I proceed to verify if a media is related to a node and get only the media with a related node?

With views I can get easily the results with this query:

```
SELECT media_field_data.mid AS mid, 
field_related_gallery_media_field_data.nid AS 
field_related_gallery_media_field_data_nid
FROM
{media_field_data} media_field_data
LEFT JOIN {node__field_related_gallery} node__field_related_gallery ON 
 media_field_data.mid = 
 node__field_related_gallery.field_related_gallery_target_id AND 
 node__field_related_gallery.deleted = '0'
 LEFT JOIN {node_field_data} field_related_gallery_media_field_data ON 
 node__field_related_gallery.entity_id = 
 field_related_gallery_media_field_data.nid
 WHERE (media_field_data.status = '1') AND (media_field_data.bundle IN 
 ('gallery')) AND (field_related_gallery_media_field_data.nid IS NOT NULL)
 LIMIT 26 OFFSET 0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to do it with a DB call? Why not use Drupal's existing functions?

```
  // Load a node by node ID.
  $nid = '213';
  $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);

  // OR load current node.
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');

  if (!empty($node)) {
    // Assumes you have a media field called "Related gallery"
    $medias = $node->get('field_related_gallery')->referencedEntities();

    foreach ($medias as $media) {
      // Do stuff with the media.
    }
  }
```